# Android Vector: Why is the stroke color not adopted?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, vector, android-vectordrawable

I took a vector xml file from a blogger and now have a different result than him. With his vector you can clearly see the edges while with my vector they only have the color gradient. However, if I replace the gradient with a monotone color, the stroke color suddenly becomes visible. Below is the code with the color gradient and here is the link to the blog:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-gradients-part1/

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="96dp"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:pathData="M1,1 H99 V99 H1Z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#111111"
                android:endX="50"
                android:endY="99"
                android:startColor="#0000ff"
                android:startX="50"
                android:startY="1"
                android:type="linear" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's already covered by the `fillColor`, you can try this it will work.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="96dp"
android:height="94dp"
android:viewportWidth="100"
android:viewportHeight="100">

<path
    android:pathData="M1,1 H99 V99 H1Z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:endX="50"
            android:endY="99"
            android:startX="50"
            android:startY="1"
            android:startColor="#0000ff"
            android:endColor="#111111"
            android:type="linear">

        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>

</path>

<path android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M1,1 H99 V99 H1Z" />

</vector>
```

Comment: But as I've already written, the blogger's vector also has a visible stroke

Comment: Yeah, I see but it's covered by the fillColor and no attr available to give the path inner padding to make stroke visible

Comment: But the question is why my stroke is not visible, although I have exactly the same text in my xml file

Comment: i don't think the xml in the article work as i already tried too but same as you mention which means need to add another path for this stroke on top of filColor to appear .